# DOM elements/innetHTML add to table from dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, append, innerhtml

Okay. This is a long one. So I have a page with a table containing various information about cars and the dealerships they came from. There is a button to add more cars with different years. This button opens a dialog. The dialog has 3 drop downs and one text input. I need the information from each drop down and the text input to add to the parent page. I'm halfway there. The information is adding the value of the input box, the text to the parent table within the "son" part of the table. I need this also to add the chosen value of the "son" drop downs on the same row of this text. One more thing. The "father" drop down needs to direct where the "son" information goes. Currently, my text is adding a new row to the bottom of the table under no specific father. I have stripped my code as much as possible so it's not overwhelming to look at, if there's a bracket missing somewhere it's an oversight. Here is the code and html for the parent page.

```
 <head>
<script>
    function updateParent1(value1,value2) {
            var table = document.getElementById("car_table");

            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            //alert(rowCount);
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            cell1.innerHTML = "";

            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            cell2.innerHTML = value2;


</script>
</head>
<body>
<legend>Vehicle Information</legend>
  <input type="text" id="shore_count" />
                  <div class="add_icon"><a href="step-1-dialog-add-shore-tanks.html" target="_blank" class="nyroModal"><img src="images/add-item-icon.png"/></a></div>
                  <table id="car_table">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Dealership</th>
                        <th>Vehicle Details</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr class="row_blue_bold father" id="father3">
                        <td colspan="2" class="father_header">John Eagle Honda</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="row_blue_bold son3">
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>Honda 2011 - Civic</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="row_blue_bold son3">
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>Honda 2008 - Accord</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="row_blue_bold father" id="father4">
                        <td colspan="2" class="father_header">John's Used Cars</td>
                        <td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="son4">
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>Toyota 2002 - Camry</td>
                      </tr>
</body>
```

and here is the iframe/dialog page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {     
        var id =3;
        for (i=0;i<parent.getDescCount();i++) {
            id++;
            var prot = $("#numbers").find(".prototype").clone();                        
            prot.find(".id").attr("value", id);
            prot.find(".apni").attr("value","");

            $("#numbers").append(prot);

        }
        //End of Add button
        $("img.exit").click(function () {
            parent.$.nmTop().close();
        });
        $("img.save").click(function () {           
            var isError = false;
            $("input").each(function(i) {                               
                if(this.value == "") {
                    isError = true;
                    var newRow = "<tr style='background:#ffff99'><td colspan='4'>Please enter the year of this vehicle.</td></tr><tr>";
                    $(this).parent().parent().before(newRow);
                }
            });

            if(isError) return;

            for(var j=0;j<document.getElementsByName("select1").length;j++) {
                parent.updateParent1(document.getElementsByName("select1").item(j).value,document.getElementsByName("text1").item(j).value);
            }
            parent.$.nmTop().close();
        });     
    }); 

      //Add button
        $("img.add").click(function () {
            var prot = $("#numbers").find(".prototype").clone().first();            
            prot.find(".apni").attr("value","");
            $("#numbers").append(prot);
        }     

</script>



<body>
    <div id="selMultipleTitle"> &nbsp;Add Vehicle Information&nbsp;</div>    
    <div id="btnExitDialog"><a href="#"><img src="images/exit.png" height="17" width="17" class="exit"/></a></div>
    <table id="numbers">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><strong>Make</strong></th>
          <th><strong>Dealership</strong></th>
          <th><strong>Model</strong></th>
          <th><strong>Year</strong></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tr>
      <tbody>
        <td><select id="fatherDeal" name="select1">
          <option selected>Select...</option>
          <option>John Eagle Honda</option>
          <option>Toyota of America</option>
          <option>John's Used Cars</option>
        </select></td>
        <td><select id="sonMake">
          <option selected>Select...</option>
          <option>Honda</option>
          <option>Toyota</option>
        </select></td>
        <td><select>
          <option selected id="sonModel">Select...</option>
          <option>Civic</option>
          <option>Accord</option>
          <option>Camry</option>
        </select></td>
        <td><input value="Enter year" id="sonComment" class="apni" name="text1"/></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tbody>  
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="align_right"><a href="#"><img src="images/cancel.gif" height="21" width="21" class="exit"/></a>&nbsp;<a href="#"><img src="images/save-icon1.png" height="21" width="21" class="save"/></a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I thought I was pretty clear about what I was asking. I have no error, I just can't figure out A. how to add anything but text to the table and B. to add the new row (of text and dropdown values) to a specific parent.

Comment: `$("Selector").append("<span>stuff</span>")` you should probably check out the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/)

Comment: I'm familiar with the jQuery docs. Can you tell me how to add the value of a drop down select to a parent table? I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You need a dropdown as a *source*

```
<select id="source">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
</select>
```

And a *target* table

```
<table id="target">
</table>
```

And of course some kind of *controller*, I used a `button`.

```
<button id="control">clickme</button>
```

Now you only have to bind an action to the button and make it append the contents you want from your *source* into your *target*.

```
$(function() {
    $('#control').click(function() {
        $("#target").append("<tr><td>"+$("#source").val()+"</td></tr>");
    });
});
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/X5DUv/

Comment: I'm getting this sorted out, thanks. Now, how do I place the new information after the chosen parent? The parent is chosen with the dealership drop down. <select id="fatherDeal" name="select1">

Comment: I assume that both documents are on the same domain; you can access the parent frames car table with jQuery using `$("#car_table", window.parent.document)`, I assume you can do the rest